# All nights a network segment brings all network down

Tags: networking, ddos

I have a medium-sized network: 45 devices with printers, a couple of DC and W10 desktops. Last week all network went down at 21:30 and, since that day, all network goes down unless I disconnect one segment from it at same time (which looks a malignant pattern by the way). In that segment there is just a printer and a couple of PCs. I have checked all of them one by one by leaving only one up each night and thouht I had found the problematic desktop. Nevertheless, I factory reset it and network keeps failing (even when I disconnect it from the network). I am getting out of ideas to try and find the problem causing the network outage.

If I look at the network switch when the problem occurs, all lights blink fast and with a constant pattern similar to when you create a loop in a switch. At that moment, I cannot even ping other devices. Whenever I disconnect said segment, problem dissapears inmediately.

I have even thought of a DDoS from an internal node but I cannot find it :-(.

Any suggestions on how to proceed and what could cause such network flooding symptoms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried replacing the switch?

Comment: Install Wireshark on any PC, run it, you may be able to see the packets that are getting spammed and that may give you a clue. More likely a bug (programming error) than a DDoS - Occam's and Hanlon's razors apply.

Comment: Maybe it is a network loop. Are there any other switches hooked up on that segment?

Comment: Thanks a lor for your help. I have added info to include resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we finally found the cause. As I suspected, the cause was a DoS attack and one of our IP cameras or two where initiating attack at specific time slots.